# Using pfSense - iPhone connections keep dropping from WiFi

Tags: wireless-networking, iphone, pfsense

pfSense version: 2.4.4-RELEASE-p3 (amd64)
WiFi adapter: D-Link DWA-556 (running in HostAP mode)
Internet: xFinity bridged to pfSense (pfSense carries the public IP on the WAN interface)

Once I set up pfSense as a WiFi (N) access point, all devices (minus phones) got a bump in connection speed.  My iPhone and wife's iPhone (X, XR) immediately dropped to 7-10 Mbps, and intermittently drop the connection.  This results in the WiFi on the phones having to get toggled off/on (not just from swipe down/tap WiFi, but from Settings - WiFi).  This has to be repeated several times and it didn't help to reset network settings on the phone.

I've not been able to 1) find a wifi channel analyzer to run from iPhone, and 2) haven't found a command-line tool to run *from pfSense* to check the channel settings or validate that the WiFi adapter has an issue.  Since laptops work and Xbox works, it seems like the issue is with something on the network layer between pfSense and that type of device?

Help!

Note: Turning off Squid and SNORT did not change the connection issues.  Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

When i tried to set up WiFi on PfSense box a year ago, i would get the exact same issue, that is:

-Extreme slowdowns

-Disconnects

And i couldnt find the exact issue, but i thought it might be hardware related (WiFi card). PfSense seems to really hate WiFi cards, and there is a small list of cards that work fine with it.

The best thing for you would be just to use a second router, disable WAN, disable DHCP and set a static IP. That way the new router would forward all traffic to pfsense, while avoiding that irritating problem. That is how am i running it now.